# Copy and Filter nested list Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of lists that looks something like:

```
[[51502 2 0 ... 0 1 1]
 [8046 2 0 ... 1 1 2]
 ....
 [40701 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]
```

In my case, every first element in the nested list is "out-of-place" and I want to remove all of them.

```
# My goal: 
[[2 2 0 ... 0 1 1]
 [2 0 ... 1 1 2]
 ....
 [1 1 ... 1 1 1]]
```

I've tried `np.delete(the_nested[i],0)` using for-loop and it gave me the error of "*could not broadcast input array*"

I've also tried to delete it manually using `del` and `pop`, but as expected, numpy didn't allow it since static.

Could anyone provide an alternative solution?

> Update: Type for the_nested is `numpy.ndarray`

*Note: I'm sorry beforehand if this post turns out to be a duplicate (hopefully not!) :(*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just index it out:

```
np.array(the_nested)[:,1:]
```

In your case:

```
the_nested = [[51502, 2, 0,  0, 1, 1],
              [8046 ,2 ,0 , 1 ,1 ,2],
              [40701, 1 ,1  ,1 ,1 ,1]]

>>> np.array(the_nested)[:,1:]
array([[2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Alternatively, with `np.delete` (no loop needed):

```
>>> np.delete(np.array(the_nested),0,axis=1)
array([[2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized the type is actually `numpy.ndarray`. I did what you wrote here, and the output didn't change. Is it because the datatype is ndarray instead of array?

Comment: @ThomasWest could you print `the_nested.shape`?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Yes, it is (50000, 40)

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko & sacul NVM! Figured it out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a list and if you don't want to use additional packages like `numpy` you can do something like this. But it involve looping. Also, it is not modifying the original list.

```
the_nested = [[51502, 2, 0,  0, 1, 1],
              [8046 ,2 ,0 , 1 ,1 ,2],
              [40701, 1 ,1  ,1 ,1 ,1]]

res = []

_ = [res.append(x[1:]) for x in the_nested]

# Output : 
[[2, 0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```